# After submitting a form an Ajax message shows up at the top of the page and disappears (how to do that?)

Tags: jquery, forms

In [this page](http://www.getfinch.com/finch/confirmation/), when you submit the form the page seems to stay as it is and it just shows a message at the top of the page saying that the message was sent.

The only part I understood was the following code:

```
jQuery(function() {
var returnMessage = ['I got the message! I will get back to you as soon as I can.'];

    jQuery('body').showMessage({

      'thisMessage':  returnMessage,
      'className':  'success',
      'opacity':  95,
      'displayNavigation': false,
      'autoClose':  true,
      'delayTime':  4000

      });
    });
```

I know that the code above makes the message appear at the top of the page.

But I can't see how is this Javascript code connected to the form.

Can anyone explain that to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the page uses the [showMessage](http://showmessage.dingobytes.com/) jQuery plugin. This plugin simply displays a message at the top, it has no connection with a form. When you navigate to the link you provided there is no need to submit a form to see the message.

The way it works is that you fill the form at the [Contact](http://www.getfinch.com/contact/) page and once you submit it you are redirected to the [Confirmation](http://www.getfinch.com/confirmation/) page which simply contains the notification message at the top.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Submitting the form triggers that message inside the [] brackets.

Comment: @janoChen, submitting the form triggers a request to the web server which redirects to the Confirmation page. This confirmation page contains the message. So technically speaking submitting the form doesn't trigger any message at all.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov So the message is automatically triggered in this new confirmation page!

Comment: @janoChen, yes the message is triggered when the confirmation page is displayed.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov But this means that the message will be displayed each time I reload the confirmation page. Is there a way of avoiding this?

Comment: @janoChen, yes each time you reload the confirmation page the message will be there. What you could do instead is set a server side variable which indicates if the message should be shown and based on it's value  you include or not the call to `.showMessage`. Another alternative is to use AJAX and in your success handler show the message (in this case you won't be navigating away from the contact page).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Thanks, I'll try those alternatives.